# Creating a session ID and applying it to events

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have event data from an app that helps tell me what people are doing inside my app.

```
userID|timestamp |name       | value |
A     | 1        |Launch     | 23 |
A     | 3        |ClickButton| Header|
B     | 2        |Launch     | 10 |
B     | 5        |ClickBanner| ad |
```

etc

I am defining a Session as anytime someone has been out of the app for more than 5 minutes, the next entry is a new session. So if you come back in after 4 minutes, it is still the same session.

I use a lag to select the previous launch timestamp, add the value of time in seconds for that and then take the difference for the next launch. So I can select the first timestamp for each 'Session'

Now I need to map each non Launch event back to the session it is a part of so I can easily analyze things such as 'What percent of sessions include an ad click?'

I'm pulling my data using HIVE and am not having success finding an efficient way to do this as my dataset is fairly large.

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query that you have.

Comment: Give a reasonable data sample that represents your use-case